# django-autocomplete-light not working with autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

Following the [tutorial](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) when I create a model with a ManyToManyField:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Person(models.Model):
    visited_countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
```

And then render a form using the `ModelSelect2Multiple` widget:

```
widgets = {
    'visited_countries': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
        url='country-autocomplete')
}
```

The data that is submitted comes in as a single value as opposed to an array, so the `Person` object is never created on form save.

Is there a way to have it come in as an array and appropriately create the ManyToMany relationship?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was how I was dealing with the data in my view. I was doing:

```
data = request.POST.dict()
form = PersonForm(data)
```

However I should have done:

```
form = PersonForm(data=request.POST)
```

Since the transformation to dictionary takes the first value.